# Generate cateogry wise ticket code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an online complain system in which when an emplyee submits his complain and the system automatically generates a ticket number. For example first employee gets the ticket
NB000001, second employee gets NB000002, third employee gets DT000001 etc where NB and DT are complain categories which the employee chooses according to the complain. How do I generate these numbers in PHP and save it in mysql such that each complain number is unique.

Here is the code I am using from PHPjabbers.com. But I am unable to make it continue from last issued ticket number and cannot make it distingiush between the two above mentioned categories.

```
<?php
function generate_numbers($start, $count, $digits) {
   $result = array();
   for ($n = $start; $n < $start + $count; $n++) {

      $result[] = str_pad($n, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

   }
   return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: How are you trying to do .. show us some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We expect you to try and write the code yourself, and if you are stuck with an error you don't understand we can help. But we won't (in most cases) write code for you.

Comment: @Ahsan Jamal  show us the code

Comment: <?php
function generate_numbers($start, $count, $digits) {
   $result = array();
   for ($n = $start; $n < $start + $count; $n++) {
 
      $result[] = str_pad($n, $digits, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
 
   }
   return $result;
}
?>